# A bar with a point sliding on it

Tags: classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

Given a smooth bar of mass $M$ and of length $L$ attached to the ceiling in a horizontal position and given a point of mass $m$ on the bar placed in the point of attachment of the bar, find the equations of motion of the point while it is sliding on the bar. At the end of the motion, the point stops at the end of the bar.

The coordinates are the angle $\varphi(t)$ between the bar and the ceiling and $r(t)$ which stands for the distance between the point of attachment and the given point. Initial conditions: $\varphi(0)=\dot{\varphi}(0)=r(0)=\dot{r}(0)=0$.

My equations are:

$$2r\dot{r}\dot{\varphi}+r^2\ddot{\varphi}-(9.81r+ML/2m)\cos\varphi=0$$
$$\ddot{r}-r\dot{\varphi}-9.81\sin\varphi=0.$$

There must appear some motion with dissipation as the massive point on the bar forces it to get the vertical position, however, Wolfram Mathematica gives a different answer, where the point goes to infinity somehow.

I consider a possibility of a mistake because of following: our given point affects the momentum of inertia of the bar. Then, my equations are different from the real ones. Is my consideration correct?

Comment: What is your Lagrangian?

Comment: Can you explain how you got these equations? They don’t seem to be correct.

Comment: @Gonçalo my Lagrangian is: $mr^2\dot{\varphi}^2/2+m\dot{r}^2/2+ML^2\dot{\varphi}^2/6+mgr\sin\varphi+ML\sin\varphi/2$

Comment: It seems correct. You should check your equations of motion. They are not compatible with your Lagrangian. For instance, the second equation should be $\ddot{r}-r\dot{\varphi}^{\color{red}{2}}-g\sin\varphi=0.$

Comment: I have just noticed that you missed a factor of $g$ in the last term of your Lagrangian.